# QJsonValue gets empty

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qjson, qjsonobject

When I make request to the time API to get the Moscow time, I'm getting empty `int` in the variable.
Here's the code:

```
QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://yandex.com/time/sync.json?geo=213")));
QEventLoop loop;
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
loop.exec();

QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);
QJsonObject root = document.object();
qDebug() << data;
qDebug() << root.value("time").toInt();
```

Here's the JSON:

```
{"time":1519489796585,"clocks":{"213":{"id":213,"name":"Moscow","offset":10800000,"offsetString":"UTC+3:00","showSunriseSunset":true,"sunrise":"07:33","sunset":"17:53","isNight":true,"skyColor":"#3f68b2","weather":{"temp":-10,"icon":"ovc","link":"/moscow"},"parents":[{"id":225,"name":"Russia"}]}}}
```

Comment: `time` is the number of `msec` since epoch (1970-01-01) .. in all cases you need to convert it to a `QdateTime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number is revised: 1519490351963, this exceeds the greater value of an integer: 2147483647, so there is no conversion to whole, a possible solution is to convert it to double:

```
// qDebug() << root["time"].toDouble();
qDebug() << root.value("time").toDouble();
```

Another possible solution is to convert it to `QVariant` and then use `toLongLong()` to use `qlonglong` which is a type of integer that supports more bits.

```
//qDebug() << root["time"].toVariant().toLongLong();
qDebug() << root.value("time").toVariant().toLongLong();
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! I've been trying to solve this for hours.